# Remove React Component contentEditable Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, components, warnings

I've created a react component which is a form within a model in a pop-up hover. But Every time I load the page the get the following Warning in the console, and I want to remove it.

Here's the warning-

```
Warning: A component is `contentEditable` and contains `children` managed by React.
It is now your responsibility to guarantee that none of those nodes are unexpectedly modified or duplicated.
This is probably not intentional.
div
FormControl@http://localhost:3001/static/js/1.chunk.js:31598:18
WithStyles@http://localhost:3001/static/js/1.chunk.js:78328:25
TextField@http://localhost:3001/static/js/1.chunk.js:52126:22
WithStyles@http://localhost:3001/static/js/1.chunk.js:78328:25
```

Please let me know if I've missed out on any information or code snippet.

Comment: If you read the warning, you can see what's the problem... You have a `contentEditable` with children managed by React... That's likely unintentional, and very likely to result in problems.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, and unlike as mentioned in the Warning that "This is probably not intentional", it in fact is intentional. I just wish to remove or hide this warning.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to suppress that warning.